# Turn Off Silverlight Plug-in Warning in Chrome

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome

I'm working with a Silverlight 3 app and using Chrome as my test browser. While debugging I keep getting the popup message:

> Plug-in Unresponsive
>
> The following plug-in is unresponsive:
> Unknown Would you like to stop i?
>
> Yes/No

How can I turn this off in Chrome?  Can VS be set to shut it off only when debugging? It's a real pain when debugging.

Thanks,

Comment: This may be obvious, but why not just use a browser without that problem for debugging? Firefox is fine in my experience for Silverlight 3, and you have to test a web app in all major browsers anyway :)

Comment: During routine dev I test using just one browser; since Chrome seems to have the most issues with Silverlight it gives me the most feedback during dev so when we do do the cross-browser testing, it's minimal.

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this. I am on Win XP SP3 and stable build of Chrome.  I like Chrome b/c it renders much faster than Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add *--disable-hang-monitor* to chrome shortcut

Comment: It would be nice to have a way to set this in user-preferences so that installing a new version of Chromium doesn't need me to remember to do this. (BTW, this should be marked as the answer!)

Answer (score 1):

Nick - are you using Chrome early builds on the Mac?  There are some known issues with Chrome/Silverlight that we are working through with the teams -- most scenarios work though.  Is this something you can share so others may verify?

Comment: I'm running it on Win XP. We're using the Telerik controls which have occasional issues running on Chrome (the editor control was giving us clipping issues, the HTML Placeholder wasn't displaying anything, etc..) Most scenarios do work, and overall Chrome works fine, just a little more buggy than the IE/FF so getting it working in Chrome helps in the long run. Just an annoying popup to deal with I was wondering if anyone knew anyway to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I set IE9 as my default browser when debugging Silverlight and switch back to Chrome afterwards. Chrome doesn't seem to communicate to Visual Studio (or vice versa) so I can't get breakpoint and exception information when using Chrome.